# What is the relation between Lille Europe and Lille Flandres railway stations?

Tags: trains, lille

I am checking the Belgian rail website for traveling to Lille. I get two options in Lille: Lille Europe and Lille Flandres.

What is the difference between these two stations? I suppose location, but is one served by more trains than the other? Do all trains stop in both? Are they completely unrelated meaning some trains go to one, others go to the other?

Which one should I pick to

1. Be near to the center?
2. Get transport to the airport?

Comment: That could be a good question but have you done any own research?

Comment: @mts I did look it up but I didn't find a good answer and I still don't understand if they points in the same line if the line  biforks and generates 2  stations... I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Lille Europe and Lille Flandres are the 2 railway stations of Lille. Those are in the same area. It takes approximately 10-15 minutes to walk from one to the other via the Euralille mall.

Not all destinations are served by each station. From Paris, you can reach both. Lille Europe is usually used for Eurostar and Thalys (ie to UK and Belgium).

The closest to Grand Place is Lille Flandres. The shuttle to the airport is between both railway stations, in front of Euralille center.